# How to properly parse special characters in JSON- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am running a SQL query in rails that then is formatted to return JSON. However, simply applying:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: { locations: @results }}
end
```

In rails to the resulting object, results in the format:

```
"locations":[
{
"id":104,
"address":"1 at\u0026t way",
"city_name":"arlington",
"state":"tx",
"zip":76011,
"latitude":32.7499,
"longitude":-97.0894
}
]
}
```

Where the street name becomes: `at\u0026t way`, instead of the correct `at&t way`.

How can rails format the JSON to allow for such special characters?

Comment: did I answer your question here Sauron?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's working as expected, it's just unicode escaping the ampersand which is part of the [JSON standard](http://json.org/). Now whoever is going to parse the JSON on the other side will pick up the the correct ampersand when the parse it back to their language of choice.  For example, if that payload came into a different rails server and we parsed it with ruby it would look like this:

(I copied your json into a `example-json.json` file for demonstration)

```
8] pry(main)> JSON.parse(IO.readlines('json-example.json').join)
=> {"locations"=>
  [{"id"=>104,
    "address"=>"1 at&t way",
    "city_name"=>"arlington",
    "state"=>"tx",
    "zip"=>76011,
    "latitude"=>32.7499,
    "longitude"=>-97.0894}]}
```